# unzip command doesn't work with Hyper Terminal

Tags: osx, zip

In Terminal we can `unzip` an archive. I tried the same command in Hyper Terminal and nothing works.

Shouldn't all the same commands work? If not, how do I make sure they do?

No error message. It just doesn't execute.

I'm talking about the Hyper Terminal.

https://hyper.is

Comment: What error message did you get?

Comment: When you're using Terminal or HyperTerminal, your computer is sending whatever you type to another device and displaying anything it gets back. That other device may be a computer, or something else like a piece of network equipment with a console port. Whatever commands are available on that other device will depend entirely on what that device *is*.

Comment: No error messages. It just doesn't execute. https://hyper.is

Comment: @tem: What system are you connected to?

Comment: macOS 10.15 Catalina

Comment: Have you tried using `tar -xvf filename.zip` instead of `unzip`?

Comment: Just found out that both commands work. But I had to write them out manually. I can't drag the file to the Hyper window like I can with Terminal/iTerm. Not very helpful when the file path is long. When dragging a file the path simply doesn't show up in the window. I'm assuming this might require a plugin from the Hyper marketplace.

Comment: The usual way to work with filenames in the terminal is to (1) `cd` into the right directory and (2) use tab completion (a feature of the shell you are running in the terminal). For me, this is much faster than drag and drop with a mouse (if this would work). You can also copy filepaths as text with Cmd-C/Cmd-V.

Comment: I disagree. If the finder window is already open in the directory of the file it's much quicker to drag drop. Otherwise cd and tab completion is effective.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about functionality of hyperterminal